# Properly capture (lambda) and safety issues in member function starting a new thread (C++11/14)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lambda, c++14

I've dug through various books and online resources and still I'm not really sure how to handle the situation where an ever-looping member function might launch a new thread that might need to access other member functions and variables (and sometimes mutate them). The following code describes the situation:

```
class Foo {
  int read_only; 
  Object some_big_object;
  std::atomic<int> read_and_write;
  // more private member variables 
  void helper_function_a(const Object& value) {
    Object copy = value.clone(); // deep copy
    std::thread t {[/*what should I put here?*/](){
    // read from read_only and WRITE to read_and_write
    if (/*some condition which is occasionally true*/)
      helper_function_b(copy);
      }};
    t.detach();
  } 
  void helper_function_b(const Object& value) {
    // change value 
  }
public:
  void update() {
    // update some_big_object;
    // read from read_only and READ OR WRITE from/to read_and_write
    helper_function_a(some_big_object);
  }
  void doSomething;
};

int main() {
  Foo f;
  while (true) {
    f.update();
  }
}
```

I know that I can put `this` inside the member function to capture everything, but I don't really want to capture everything, just the things I use, if possible, and nothing else. My real class is more complicated and also features variables that should remain immutable but which I cannot declare const (because I initialise them within the body of the constructor) - it feels safer to make sure that the lambda only has access to the things it uses. So what should I put in there?

Then what about this design? it feels wrong - but is it? and why? Note that in my real class (which is a lot more complex) `helper_function_a` fails - I'm still not sure where exactly is the bug, but If i remove the lambda and make it single threaded it does work. In my app I use helper_function_a to perform file IO of big objects while updating an animation - it doesn't feel write to do both tasks from the same thread.

Finally, is it safe to use read_and_write the way I do?

Comment: If you want to use members of the class you must capture `this`, there's really no way around it.

Comment: Your code is calling `helper_function_b(...)` (a method)... and you don't want to capture `this`?

Comment: I've been thinking of something like `&(this->helper_function_b)` (which won't compile of course). But your comments make it rather explicit that there's no way around it..

Answer (score 1):

if you use member function inside lambda then you should capture `this`.
You should also think about the lifetime of `this` and the threads created in `helper_function_a`.
I may recommend you to use some kind of thread pool inside Foo object and wait/interrupt all the threads in the destructor

If you don't want to capture `this` you may try to move `helper_function_b` (with all used in helper_function_b data) to some member of `Foo` and capture that member (don't forget about it's lifetime)

If you need `const` members with long initialisation you may use functions to build them:

```
Foo::Foo(args ...):
    member(build_member(args ...)),
    ...
{};
```

Another way to control lifetime is to use shared pointers and std::enable_shared_from_this like in [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/allocation/server.cpp) example

Comment: and when `build_member` might emit some exception? as when reading some file or when initialising hardware? And what kind of function should `build_member` be? some static free function in the body of the implementation file maybe?  or better in some anonymous `namespace` ?

Comment: You may catch and process exceptions thrown in `build_member`. Like [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm). `build_member` may be simple free function or static member function. Whatever you like